# iPhone: Save boolean into Core Data

Tags: iphone, core-data, boolean, uiswitch

I have set up one of my core data attributes as a Boolean.  Now, I need to set it, but XCode keeps telling me that it may not respond to setUseGPS.

```
[ride setUseGPS: useGPS.on];
```

What is the method for setting a boolean in core data?  All my other attributes are set this way, and they work great.  So, not sure why a boolean does not work to be set this way?

Answer (score 134, accepted):

Core Data "does not have" a Boolean type (it does, but it is an NSNumber).

So to set the equivalent of useGPS = YES.

```
[entity setUseGPS:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
```

And the other way around:

```
BOOL isGPSOn = [[entity useGPS] boolValue];
```

**Update:**
As pointed out by SKG, With literals in Objetive-C you can now do it in a simpler way:

```
[entity setUseGPS:@YES];

BOOL isGPSOn = entity.useGPS.boolValue;
```

Comment: You can set the values like this also:  `object.isGPSOn = @YES;`

Comment: Apparently, I can actually see the Boolean type in the dropdown when creating a new Attribute in core data editor. What about that?

Answer (score 18):

As an alternative approach to the accepted answer, you can simply change the typing from an NSNumber* to a BOOL in the managed object interface definition, such as:

```
@property (nonatomic) BOOL useGPS;   // Notice that the 'retain' is also removed as we're now dealing with a scalar rather than an NSObject
```

Various alternative approaches are discussed [here](http://www.livetotry.com/2010/12/04/core-data-and-booleans/), but [Chris Hanson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/714/chris-hanson)'s response was most illuminating for me, especially:

> If you have a numeric attribute
>   (including a boolean attribute) that's
>   required, you can just type it as a
>   scalar instead, and Core Data will do
>   the right thing:
>
> @property (nonatomic) BOOL isDone;
>
> Even if the attribute is optional,
>   that'll still work - it'll just
>   conflate "not present" with "false."

and for a more aligned Cocoa implementation:

> One other thing you might want to do
>   is name the property "done" and just
>   specify the getter as "isDone." That's
>   the usual Cocoa naming convention:
>
> @property (nonatomic, getter=isDone)
>   BOOL done;
>
> Then you can write "if (item.done) {
>   ... }" or "item.done = NO;" and the
>   compiler will still generate -isDone
>   for accesses of the property.

Thanks Chris, and hope that this helps someone.

Comment: I'm seeing a crash on iOS 4.x when I try this method. Here's the message: "Property 'bar' is a scalar type on class 'Foo'.  Cannot generate a getter method for it." I've tried setting the attribute type to Boolean in the Core Data model, and I've also tried Integer 16. I get the same crash either way. Am I missing something? Perhaps I'll just go back to using NSNumber.

Comment: As far as I know, this does not work on NSManagedObject subclasses.

Answer (score 2):

Just to complement @RickiG answer, the way to create a `NSNumber` from a `Bool`and vice-versa in Swift (at least since v4.2) is:

```
let nsNumberFromBool = NSNumber(booleanLiteral: true) // or false
let boolFromNSNumber = nsNumberFromBool.boolValue
```

Answer (score 0):

The "fix" for this (IMHO, it's a bug in Apple's SDK) is to add the following code to your CoreData-generated class. NB: if you do this in a category, in a separate file, then you don't have to re-copy/paste it each time you regenerate the CoreData classes inside Xcode

```
- (BOOL)useGPS
{
    [self willAccessValueForKey:@"useGPS"];
    BOOL myuseGPS = [[self primitiveUseGPS] boolValue];
    [self didAccessValueForKey:@"useGPS"];
    return myuseGPS;
}

- (void)setUseGPS:(BOOL)newValue
{
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"useGPS"];
    [self setPrimitiveUseGPS:[NSNumber numberWithBool:newValue]];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"useGPS"];
}
```

Comment: This leads to conflicting types when I compile. Should I be changing the types of the existing NSNumber properties?

Comment: @Daniel Wood - don't change the existing types: CoreData requires them to be NSNumber. The compile warnings are irritating - the easy workaround is to rename the above two methods to "useGPSAsBool" and "setUseGPSAsBool". NB: you can still access the property, only it's now called "GPSAsBool", e.g. "if( myCoreDataObject.GPSAsBool )"

Comment: After reading the following in the docs I decided not to bother with any of this and just convert from NSNumber in my code: "The advantages of allowing Core Data to manage its own storage usually outweigh any advantages of interacting directly with scalar values" http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdNSAttributes.html

Comment: @Daniel - the text you quote is referring to a different issue. That text does NOT apply in this case - we are indeed "allowing Core Data to manage its own storage", we're just adding 2 convenience methods to make it use booleans the way that ObjectiveC expects. I expect that Apple will eventually add a fix to their own code that is essentially the same as this.