# Why I can only fetch one object from an array Core Data Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

My goal is to take a filteredArray object and persist it using Core Data. I created an Entity called "CoreDataArrayObj" and modeled all of the attributes based upon what exists in the object. In my ViewDidload I empty the array, delete old saved data, and then save and fetch data. I can get the data to save to the array for more than 40 different objects, but when I go to fetch the data, I only receive 1. Why can't I fetch more than 1 object from the array?

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

func getContext () -> NSManagedObjectContext {
 let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
 return appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
 }

 class FilterVC: UIViewController {

var filterCoreDataArray = [CoreDataArrayObj]()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    filterCoreDataArray = []   //Empty Array
    deleteCoreDataArray().     // deletePreviousData
    saveFilterArray()          // save and fetch. 
    print("Core data Array \(filterCoreDataArray)"

    }
```

Functions

```
 func saveFilterArray() {
    let context = getContext()

    let transc = CoreDataArrayObj(context: context)

    for prop in filteredResults.filteredArray {

        transc.allImages = prop.allImages as NSArray?
        (transc.ageOfHouse) = Int16(prop.ageOfHouse)
        transc.firstImg = prop.firstImg
        transc.city = prop.city
        transc.bedroo = Int16(prop.bedrooms)

        do {
         try context.save()
            self.LoadFilterArray()

        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        } catch {

        }
    }
      }


 func LoadFilterArray() {
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<CoreDataArrayObj> = CoreDataArrayObj.fetchRequest()

    do {
        filterCoreDataArray = try getContext().fetch(fetchRequest)

        print(filterCoreDataArray)
        for trans in filterCoreDataArray  {
           print(trans.images)
            print("age of house\(trans.ageOfHouse )")
           print("firstImg\(trans.firstImg)")
            print("city\(trans.city)")
            print("propertyType\(trans.bedroo)")
        }

    } catch {
        print("Error with request: \(error)")
    }

}
func deleteCoreDataArray() {
    let context = getContext()

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "CoreDataArrayObj")

    let result = try? context.fetch(fetchRequest)
    let resultData = result as! [CoreDataArrayObj]

    for object in resultData {
        context.delete(object)
        print("delted saved")
    }

    do {
        try context.save()
        print("saved")
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    } catch {

    }


}
```

Comment: You create only a *single* managed object. In the loop, you just modify the properties of that object.

Comment: Are you saying what I should do, or what I am doing?

Comment: I described what you are currently doing ...

Comment: Ya I thought so, just wanted to clarify. Do you know the proper method to achieve saving multiple managed objects?

Comment: @MartinR the other question does not have a confirmed answer.

Comment: It has 4 answers and all describe the solution: Move the object creation into the loop, so that one object per iteration is created.

Comment: None was declared answered by the person asking the question, and they all have slightly different answers. But thank you for directing me to the page. much appreciated.